# White lines shown in rendering of ngx-leaflet layers

Tags: angular, leaflet, mapbox, ngx-leaflet

Using Leaflet 1.3.1,
ngx-leaflet 2.5,
Angular 4.4.5

I am rendering the map in a modal and in some cases, white lines will form on the map:

[image: like so]

Has anyone else experienced this and know what could be causing it?

Comment: that's the [equator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equator)

Comment: Nice to see a screenshot of your issue, but it is not enough to be able to help you. It might very well be the tile images themselves, representing the equator, as suggested by PierreDuc. Or it might be a rendering bug. Make sure you share enough code for people to be able to reproduce your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Might be a case of https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3575. Difficult to know without more info, though.